# Android: MotionEvent Need some clarification of GetHistoricalX and GetHistoricalY

Tags: android, xamarin, move, touch-event

In my application, I required to draw strokes to the view with touches. I would have to save a previous coordinated when touch down and touch move (after processed the touch move). When I looked at the API, there is GetHistoricalX and GetHistoricalY.

> 1) How does these historical data work. Will they ever be removed?
>
> 2) Will it start keeping all the historical data when the touch start moving?

Since I using Xamarin Form which also implement for IOS. Does IOS has the same thing as this.

Answer (score 4):

#### Android:

On Android, `GetHistoricalX|Y` will contain the X/Y that have **not** been reported since the last `ACTION_MOVE` event (i.e. this are batched into a single touch event for efficiency).

> The coordinates are "historical" only insofar as they are older than the current coordinates in the batch; however, **they are still distinct from any other coordinates reported in prior motion events**. To process all coordinates in the batch in time order, first consume the historical coordinates then consume the current coordinates.

Note: Since there is no standard Input Sampling rates defined for `/dev/input/event0`, the rate is determined by the hardware developer and how their digitizer grid driver is written/configured. Android will then collect the number of samples available and offer those to the developer within the historical data along with the most current X/Y sample. If everyone knows how to get this frequency from the OS, I would love to know ;-)

You can use the `GetHistorySize` to get the number of "points" available, process them first and then process the current X/Y, but remember these are only the locations since the last move batch event.

There is sample Java code under the **Batching** section  @ https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

#### iOS:

On iOS, the number of touch events reported are based on a 60hz sampling rate of their digitizer. Some iDevices have a faster frequency (newer iPads at 120hz & iPad Pro at 240hz). These 'extra" points are reported within the `coalescedTouchesForTouch` method (`Xamarin.iOS` = `GetCoalescedTouches`).

Note: iOS even has `predictedTouchesForTouch` (`Xamarin.iOS` = `GetPredictedTouches`) that *might* be available within the `UIEvent`. These can be used to "pre-draw" where the user might be moving to, Apple has dev code samples of this when using the Apple Pencil to prevent a visual "lag" from the tip of the pencil...

#### Net Result:

In the end, if you need to preserve a history of X/Y touch locations in order to replay them, you will need to store these yourself as neither iOS or Android is going to buffer these outside of a touch event.

Comment: Yea, I have tried the historical data, and now producing smooth curve. I think i want to sample them but not sure how to do it coz I dont' think we need to store every single touch move to produce bezier curve.

Comment: Do you know any good algorithm best to store the points which good in traversal and insertion? At the moment, I made a QuadTree which partition the space into 4 area when the eraser button selected: Top left, top right, Button left and Bottom Right but to create this tree is quite expensive for that numerous of points in my scenerio.

Comment: @Simon It all really depends upon what the end result needs to be, there is the RDP algorithm & lots of variants) to simplify the number of points in a curve and achieve a "similar" result. A QuadTree *might* be what you need for your use-case...I'm found simple C# sorted lists fast enough for some cases, I've used Octrees and stored the touch pressure as the Z-coord, etc..,  Posting a sample of what you are trying to achieve to the StackOverflow's C# & algorithm tags would be good to see what your needs are.

Comment: I saw a person who have a surface pro (I think that is a surface pro), he show me the office or some other application. He use the stylus to draw some stroke and then remove it. That is result I wanted to achieve.